# Can we get others involved while still in private beta?

Tags: discussion, support

I just asked a question on genealogy.se. The site put a "know someone who can help..." comment and I'd like to follow their advice and forward a link to other experts. Will that link work while the site is in private beta? I don't want to frustrate experts by sending them a link they can't use. That might make them less likely to come back in future once we're in public beta. Conversely I do want to get others involved if that is possible at this point in time.

Comment: Closed as *no longer relevant.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that link will work without prior access. The site will be entering *public* beta in the next few days, but in the meantime, you can use the 'invite fellow experts' interface located in the right sidebar. That will allow your fellow genealogists into the site.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't even notice the invite in the sidebar until you pointed it out.

Answer (score 0):

No worries now! We are now in Public Beta! Invite away!